# How to use a custom deserializer with Spring @RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, http-request-parameters

I have an interface that's not aware of its implementations (module-wise):

```java
public interface SomeInterface {
}
```

and an enum implementing it:

```java
public enum SomeInterfaceImpl {
}
```

I have a `@RestController`:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<SomeClass> find(@RequestParam(value = "key", required = false) SomeInterface someInt,
                            HttpServletResponse response){
}
```

Although Jackson is aware that it should deserialize `SomeInterface` as `SomeInterfaceImpl` as follows:

```java
public class DefaultSomeInterfaceDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SomeInterface> {
    @Override
    public SomeInterface deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return parser.readValuesAs(SomeInterfaceImpl.class).next();
    }
}
```

and:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyJacksonConfiguration implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if(bean instanceof Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder){
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = (Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) bean;
            builder.deserializerByType(SomeInterface.class, new DefaultSomeInterfaceDeserializer());
        } 
        return bean;
    }
}
```

and successfully serializes and deserializes `SomeInterface` as `SomeInterfaceImpl` in the `@RequestBody`, it doesn't seem to have any effect on mapping `SomeInterface` to `SomeInterfaceImpl` with `@RequestParam`. How do I overcome this?

Comment: converting request params doesn't use jackson (why should it it isn't json). You need a custom `Converter` for that which converts from a `String` to your implemenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `Converter` in the application context as M.Denium suggested does the job:

```java
@Component
public class SomeInterfaceConverter implements Converter<String, SomeInterface> {

    @Override
    public SomeInterface convert(String value) {
        return new SomeInterfaceImpl(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't. You just need a proper `Converter`.

Comment: not working method convert does not get invoked

Comment: @M.Deinum Please explain?

Comment: Why should I explain an answer that I haven't given? How to register converters is explained in the documentation (which sadly people do not tend to read).